# how to get real path image from sdcard after cropping?

Tags: java, android, uri, crop, absolute-path

i have problem in my project. i want to pass cropped image to other activity. i've done my crop method but i cant get the real path of it. i've searched before how to get the path but all ways that i found didnt work. its always give me null path. so if you guys can help me, please answer my question..
here is my code

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    ImageView imgView;
    private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
    String realPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                i.putExtra("crop","true");
                i.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                i.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                i.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                i.putExtra("outputY", 200);
                i.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(i,2);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String type = data.getType();
            Log.i("TAG", "Pick completed: " + uri + " " + type);
            if (uri != null)
            {
                String path = uri.toString();
                if (path.toLowerCase().startsWith("file://"))
                {
                    // Selected file/directory path is below
                    path = (new File(URI.create(path))).getAbsolutePath();
                    Log.e("ini", path);
                }

            }

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap img = extras.getParcelable("data");
            imgView.setImageBitmap(img);
        }


    }
```

if i got the real path, i can pass the path using intent and apply it to the next imageview. all i need is the path. thanks

Comment: Pass the uri to the other activity.

Comment: `String path = uri.toString();`. Well why isnt that good enough? Please tell how that path looks like. Also tell what uri.getPath() delivers.

Comment: it should be delivers the absolute path of the image. but in my project, the Uri uri = data.getData(); is null. so, the branching process if(uri != null) is never done.

Comment: Until now you did not tell about Bitmap img =.

Comment: Bitmap img = extas.getparcelable("data") that code is apply the cropped image to the bitmap.

Comment: You are supposed to tell if it works of course. What it tries to do everybody can see.

Answer (score 0):

Source URI present in data extraBundle.

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap img = extras.getParcelable("data");
imgView.setImageBitmap(img);

Uri selectedImageUri = Uri.parse(extras.get("src_uri").toString());
String realPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);


public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```